# MAGENTO: Get id, image, thumb and price of the products in a subcategory in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, magento-1.8

I would like extract in SQL (no php) the id, image url, thumb url and price of all the products in a specific subcategory in Magento.

I'm using this approach but i don't know where I can find the other information (price, image url, thumb url).
Can you help me, please?

This is my approach:

```
    SELECT *
FROM mg_catalog_product_entity AS p
LEFT JOIN mg_catalog_category_product AS cp
          ON p.entity_id = cp.product_id
LEFT JOIN mg_catalog_category_entity AS c
          ON cp.category_id = c.entity_id
LEFT JOIN mg_catalog_category_entity_varchar AS cat_varchar
          ON     c.entity_id = cat_varchar.entity_id  AND cat_varchar.attribute_id = 111
LEFT JOIN mg_catalog_product_entity_varchar AS prod_varchar
          ON     p.entity_id = prod_varchar.entity_id  AND prod_varchar.attribute_id = 96
 WHERE 1 
     AND c.entity_id = 4;
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to left join all of

```
`catalog_product_entity_*` tables that exist in Magento
```

And use `catalog_eav_attribute` to get the keys to append the labels onto the left joined values from the eav tables.

After filter the data needed.

If you want to simplify the joining, turn on database debug, check the output when the you load a product page or admin product page and replicate the joins used by the orm:

> m1\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php

Line 103:

```
protected $_debug               = true;
```

Line 117:

```
protected $_logAllQueries       = true;
```

Check output in:

> m1\var\debug\pdo_mysql.log

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query for everything except the thumb, simply replace the **category_id** in the **WHERE** clause to whatever category you want to analyze:

---

SELECT DISTINCT catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.entity_id AS `id`,
                catalog_product_entity.sku,
                catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.value AS `image url`,
                catalog_product_index_price.price AS `price`
  FROM ((magento.catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
          catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
         INNER JOIN magento.catalog_product_entity catalog_product_entity
            ON (catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.entity_id =
                   catalog_product_entity.entity_id))
        INNER JOIN
        magento.catalog_product_index_price catalog_product_index_price
           ON (catalog_product_index_price.entity_id =
                  catalog_product_entity.entity_id))
       INNER JOIN magento.catalog_category_product catalog_category_product
          ON (catalog_category_product.product_id =
                 catalog_product_entity.entity_id)
 WHERE (catalog_category_product.**`category_id`** = '**23**')
ORDER BY catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.entity_id ASC